# Modifying pagination offsets in Links on page

Tags: php, pagination

I want to create updated URL when `Next 1000` button is clicked on the current page. i.e incrementing `number` by 1000 every time `Next 1000` is clicked.

e.g: If the current URL is

```
mywebsite.com/people.php?number=0
```

`Next 1000` should be saying:

```
 mywebsite.com/people.php?number=1000
```

And so on it continues every time button is clicked

```
<?php
$count = 1000;
?>

<a href="people.php?number=<?php echo $_GET['number'] + $count ;?>">Next 1000</a>
```

I know there are a ton of pagination scripts out there. I'm using jQuery to fetch 1000 records at a time.

I just want a button to allow the users to load the next 1000 if they want to.

Comment: You have the answer right there don't you??

Comment: what's wrong with what you currently have?

Comment: i am an idiot, as i wrote my question i got the code right! i looked at it and tried it and it worked! seriously need a coffee or a break lol

Comment: it worked except i had to add an echo statement into the php

Comment: The $count++ doesn't need the ++ on the end. That increments the value of $count after it's been referenced. Tt doesn't really matter in your example but if you were to look at the value of $count, after that line, it would be 1001.

Comment: Nobody has pointed out the blatant XSS vulnerability in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to do some checks on the input, but this is the basic answer:

```
<a href="people.php?number=<?=$_GET['number']+1000?>">Next 1000</a>
```

Safer bet would be:

```
<?
$increment = (is_numeric($_GET['number']))?$_GET['number']+1000:1000;
?>
<a href="people.php?number=<?=$increment?>">Next 1000</a>
```

Comment: i like your answer and thank you, i will up-vote but what i was after was a simple one line increment. I have placed an extra comment into my original post

Comment: Thanks, you don't need the `echo` - you can use the php shorthand method by just having `<?=$VALUE?>` that will echo the value...

Comment: @jonnypixel, stap'   answer is nice, i suggest just two things: 1) Use ctype_digit() instead of is_numeric(), it will be more secure because doesn't allow float numbers. The shortag `<?=$increment?>` isn't allowed in all hostings, so preffer to use the default way with `echo`.